Unable to Override node-config folder
I`m trying to follow the package documentation, but it just doesn't work.
I want to use config folder at project/src/config
My project/src/config/file.ts
process.env['NODE_CONFIG_DIR'] = `./${__dirname}/`;
// process.env['NODE_CONFIG_DIR'] = `${__dirname}/`; Also tried this
import * as config from 'config';
console.log(`PATH: ${process.env['NODE_CONFIG_DIR']}`); // prints the right directory

const cfg = config.get('myProp'); <--- ERROR!


Still doesnt work. I get the warning message:
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/user/your/directory/config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.


but also the error
node_modules/config/lib/config.js:179
    throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');

Error: Configuration property "myProp" is not defined


obs: If I move the folder to project/config it works.
obs2: I`m using TSX package to run my project.
